# Ассемблер Hello World

Tags: ассемблер

Приветствую. пожалуйста помогите разобраться с компиляцией и линковкой в ассемблере.

```
.model flat, stdcall
.data
message db 'Hello World',13,10,0
.code
.start:
      mov ah, 09h
      mov edx, offset message
      int 21h
end start
```

Стандартный Hello World!
Компилирую так

```
ml /Cx /coff hello.asm /link /subsystem:console /entry:start
```

результатом является краш программы. В отладчике показывает что возникает ошибка ACCESS_VIOLATION в момент исполнения инструкции int 21h. Изначально думал что это из-за особенностей windows 7. Но сделав то же самое на си, и разобрав потом файл с помощью IDA pro увидел там тот же самый int 21h который довольно успешно исполнялся. Подскажите пожалуйста как быть?

Comment: Под windows в пользовательском режиме (в пользовательском приложении, а не ядре или драйвере) забудьте об использовании прерываний.

Comment: Спасибо большое за Ваш ответ. Но почему отладчики выдают ту же самую int 21h в работающем приложении?

Comment: Простите уж, но напомнило старую байку, как двое спорят до хрипоты - натурная съемка или постановка - мол, глянь, как тут вдарил! так он не мог полететь - явная постановка! Да ты, болван, физику не знаешь! - ну и так далее... Приходит третий, офигевает и говорит "Ребята, это ж "Том и Джерри"". Ребята, это ж функция DOS! Если 32-разрядная Windows и сделать выполнимый файл DOS, ну, тогда...

Comment: @АндрейБеспалов вечером постараюсь подробный ответ дать.

Comment: Благодарю Вас. Буду ждать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, вы компилируете ваш код как 32-битное консольное приложение (ключ `/subsystem:console`). В обычном пользовательском приложении (не ядре или драйвере) под Windows использовать исключения DOS или BIOS нельзя.

Можно скомпилировать программу как 16-битный досовский исполняемый файл, но рабочий код будет выглядеть немного по-другому:

```
.model small 
.stack 100h
.data
message db 'Hello World',13,10,'$' ; для функции 9h прерывания 21h конец строки должен быть обозначен как символ '$', а не 0
.code
start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    mov dx, offset message
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    mov ah, 4Ch
    int 21h
end start
```

Компиляция (masm32):

```
C:\masm32\bin\ml /c hello.asm
C:\masm32\bin\link16 hello.obj,,nul,nul,nul
```

Выполнить полученный исполняемый файл можно несколькими способами:

1. Запустив его под DOS
2. Запустив его под Windows линейки Win 9x (от 95 до Me). Это настоящее выполнение кода без эмуляции.
3. Запустив его под 32-разрядной Windows линейки NT (в том числе Win XP, Win 7 и даже Win 10, насколько я понимаю - но проверить это не могу). Это будет запуск через встроенный в систему эмулятор [NTVDM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0_DOS).
4. На любой Windows (и не только) системе с помощью эмулятора [DosBox](http://www.dosbox.com/).

По поводу прерывания `int 21h` в программах под Windows. В каждом (почти каждом) приложении Windows есть код-"заглушка", который выполняется при попытке запуска приложения из-под DOS. В этом случае на экран выведется сообщение типа `"This program cannot be run in DOS mode."` Вывод там происходит как раз с помощью 21h прерывания. При обычном запуске приложения под Windows этот код не выполнится. Если попытаться использовать прерывание под Windows, вы получите ошибку.

В качестве исключения можно использовать прерывание `int3` (команда так и выглядит, без пробела), которое специально предназначено для остановки выполнения программы, и вызова отладчика.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое. Теперь я все понял.