# Прерывания в блоке asm

Tags: c++, ассемблер

Я хочу написать аналог функции getch(), используя при этом ассемблер, вот код который есть

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    __asm {
        pusha

        mov ah, 08h
        int 21h

        popa
    }

    cout << "Test" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Но программа всегда крашится, что делать?

Comment: так нельзя -  у Вас же не дос. Но никто не мешает вызвать функцию getch из ассемблера.

Comment: По поводу вызова: Суть в том, что я сам хочу написать полную копию этой функции асм. средствами, а как тогда можно совершить прерывание?

Comment: Потому что прерывания (с некоторыми оговорками) будут работать только под DOS, а вы скорее всего компилируете в 32-битный код под Windows. См. [Ассемблер Hello World](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/780743/1365).

Comment: @insolor В x64, это просто сишка, с кодом асма

Comment: Написать "полный аналог" на асм будет достаточно сложно - все равно нужно будет вызывать api винды или линукса.

Comment: @Razor, под Windows `getch` использует не прерывания, а функцию WinAPI [ReadConsole](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsole). Под 64 битным Windows прерывания DOS не доступны от слова совсем.

Comment: Поставить виртуальную машину DOS и работать в ней :)

Comment: был бы вопрос, как собрать с помощью MSVC или gcc программу на C/C++ под дос он бы был очень интересен...